# Is it possible make a button to change customer group?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I have 3 customer groups and my store already sets the customer to their group automaticly.
What I'm trying to do is allow the customer in group 2 change their group to 3 (and vice-versa) clicking a button in the cart page. Is it possible?
I'm trying to use:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setData( 'group_id', 3 );
$customer->save();
```

But how can I save this changes?

I'm using version 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to create a controller then you put your code inside.
2. You call your controller in a button like this: `$this->getUrl('modulefontname/modulename/action');`
3. Your button should look like this:

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('modulefontname/modulename/action'); ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Change customer group') ?></button>
   ```